# NestJS ExceptionHandler undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

On one day my NestJS application was running fine, on the other it stopped running and the only thing it says in the logs is the below. The process doesn't stop, it just freezes in this message:

```
[Nest] 17260  - 19/11/2022, 17:43:48   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] undefined
```

I've tried to update all my libraries, but it didn't work.

Since it doesn't say much, I'm not sure what I'd need to share to help debugging this, please let me know.

NestJS version:

```
 "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
 "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
 "@nestjs/core": "^9.2.0",
 "@nestjs-modules/mailer": "^1.8.1",
 "googleapis": "^109.0.1",
 "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
 "hbs": "^4.2.0",
 "nodemailer": "^6.8.0",
```

I've tried to update the libraries, delete node_modules folder and reinstall, restart VSCode and system, tried to run in the last two commits, which were working fine, update Node to v19, clone the project and setup as it was the 1st time.

I was expecting the server to run.

UPDATE: I've found the module that introduced this issue. I'm not sure why though as it stopped working suddenly.

It's a mail module that I created, so I'm guessing the issue is somewhere here. If I comment disable the module, my app starts fine:

```
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { google } from 'googleapis';
import { join } from 'path';
import { MailService } from './mail.service';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => {
        const { OAuth2 } = google.auth;
        const redirectUri = 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground';
        const clientId = config.get('CLIENT_ID');
        const refreshToken = config.get('REFRESH_TOKEN');
        const clientSecret = config.get('CLIENT_SECRET');
        const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUri)
        oauth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: refreshToken });

        const accessToken: string = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          oauth2Client.getAccessToken((err, token) => {
            if (err) {
              reject("Failed to create access token :(");
            }
            resolve(token);
          });
        });

        return {
          transport: {
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
              type: 'OAuth2',
              user: config.get('MAIL_USER'),
              accessToken,
              clientId,
              refreshToken,
              clientSecret
            },
          },
          defaults: {
            from: `"Precyn" <${config.get('MAIL_FROM')}>`,
          },
          template: {
            dir: join(__dirname, 'templates'),
            adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
            options: {
              strict: true,
            },
          },
        }
      },
      inject: [ConfigService]
    }),
  ],
  providers: [MailService],
  exports: [MailService],
})
export class MailModule { }
```

Comment: looks like you got an exception somewhere. I guess it would be hard to find the issue without the full code

Comment: @MicaelLevi, just updated my question with new information I've found

Comment: btw, a tip: use the lock file when installing your dependencies (are you using NPM? then use `npm ci` instead of `npm i`). Otherwise things might start stop working out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

OK let me explain. I think this part of the code causes the problem:

```
reject("Failed to create access token :(");
```

You are rejecting a *String*. Probably a catch block in nest will handle this and expects an **Error** object that has a *message* field; So when it tries to print the message field you see *undefined* in the console because `someErrorInstance.message` is valid in JS and has *undefined* value!

If you change that line to following one, hopefully you can see the error message in console:

```
reject(new Error("Failed to create access token :("));
```